# Create Folder on SFTP server iOS

Tags: ios, sftp

I have tried [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/CreateDirController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-CreateDirController_h-DontLinkElementID_8) for performing Basic FTP operation on remote server.(e.g Download file, Upload file and Create Directory on sftp Server).But getting Stream Open error/kCFStreamErrorDomainFTP. Please help me on some of my questions.

1) is this sample code will work on SFTP?

-) In CreateDirController.m,

I am getting networkStream nil on

```
self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease( 
            CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url) 
        );
```

for SFTP server.

2) Can i use NSURLSession NSURLSession Api for SFTP request(Create Directory on SFTP server and List directory of SFTP server)?

Comment: did you tried a third party option (to use or study the code) https://github.com/shien7654321/STFTPNetwork

Comment: 2) No, you can't